# How does method chaining work?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, calling-convention, method-call

How does `getRequestDispatcher("xxx")` get called from `getServletContext()` in the example below? How does calling procedures like this work in general? Please give me a clear picture about this context.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
dispatcher.include(request, response);
```

Comment: Did you try Google - https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=getrequestdispatcher%20jsp

Comment: Wikipedia(!) has [an acceptable article on what method chaining is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining).  In short you are taking the return value of one method call and calling methods on that return value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getServletContext()` returns a `ServletContext` object, which has a method called `getRequestDispatcher()`. Your line of code is just shorthand for two method calls, and is equivalent to this code:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = context.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
```

Answer (score 0):

in general, [method chaining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) is a good practice achieving [fluent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) and flexible interfaces.
Generally... to achieve it, you just do your code and return the current object. For example, in Java:

```
public Criterios<T> setOrdem(String campo, String direcao) {
    getOrdenacao().set(campo, direcao);
    return this;
}

public Criterios<T> setOrdem(String campo) {
    return setOrdem(campo, Ordenacao.Direcao.ASC);
}

public final Criterios<T> setPagina(int pagina) {
    getPaginacao().setPagina(pagina);
    return this;
}

public final Criterios<T> setQuantidade(int quantidade) {
    getPaginacao().setQuantidade(quantidade);
    return this;
}
```

Returning the current object provides the same API over and over... but, by each iteration the object gets changed, step by step, orderly.